# How do I install an IONIC theme from market.ionicframework.com?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to know 3 things:

1. Are the pre-built ionic themes like the catalog of themes in Wordpress?
2. How do I install a theme in the ionic 4 framework?
3. Once a  theme is bought for ionic, is it reusable on multiple applications?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think you are new in Ionic. I am try to answer to your all questions.

1. Ionic theme is not like word press plugin. its like HTML template.
2. If you have theme means. you can go inside the directory and give the command `npm install` all dependency packages are installed in ionic.
3. If the design and pages same you can use. Else you can not use like word press plugin.

Comment: Thank you ! and yes i'm new in ionic :)

Comment: To install the theme I have to copy the archive rar in which folder?
Before you run the command "npm install"

Comment: I searched and found it just unzipped the archive of the theme files and run the command "npm install" with the CLI.
I give you a tip never bought a theme made in ionic version 1, 2, 3 must absolutely be in v4.
Bye